# error in creating excel file

Tags: java, excel

```
import java.io.File.*; 
import java.util.Date; 
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.read.biff.File;
import jxl.write.*;
public class Excela {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
        
    }
}
```

i run this code in but it gives following error

> **Multiple markers at this line**
>
> **- The method createWorkbook(File) in the type Workbook is not applicable for the arguments (File)**
>
> **- The constructor File(String) is undefined**

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `File`without asterix:

```
import java.io.File;
```

and remove `import jxl.read.biff.File;`

Comment: i do it but it still gives error Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type IOException
 - Line breakpoint:Excela [line: 8] - main
  (String[])

Comment: @AyzaAliKhan Add a try catch block arround the line.

Comment: i am running it in ecclipse it should be created i thought or i have to give the destination address of a file ?

Comment: @AyzaAliKhan Sorry can't get you.